# The transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'

Tags: azure

Dears,
We are facing problem with temp DB on our CM environment deployed on Azure.
we reached the transactions that caused the problem and solved by killing these transactions.
but i can not reach the pacific reason for this problem and its keep showing up every 2 weeks .

we got this error message :
The transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'

Comment: You need to schedule regular backups

Comment: can you please give me more details ?  and how to do this on azure portal

Comment: Just google your question title. Your question doesn't really belong here - it's not Sitecore related. You need to visit ServerFault or one of those.